# Turn on light (bulb) with Arduino UNO and PIR Sensor

Tags: arduino, arduino-uno

im trying to turn on the light (bulb) with my arduino UNO and one module with 4 relays. I can do it with one LED but with an bulb i can't. I have connected the wires like in the photo:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/GUuAS.jpg

I need a 1k ohm resistor or the module include it??

Here the bulb that I have:

http://i57.tinypic.com/10dbp90.jpg

Thanks!!!

Comment: Do you know there is an arduino site as well? http://arduino.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Sorry, I did not know it, Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

In your wiring picture it appears that the only source of power is what the Arduino is getting from the USB cable. The purpose of a relay is typically to control the flow of a higher voltage source (such as multiple small batteries in series, a larger battery, or a wall outlet) using a lower voltage control signal (e.g. one of your Arduino's GPIO pins). The maximum current from VCC to ground that can be draw without damaging your Arduino is 200 mA ([source](http://playground.arduino.cc/Main/ArduinoPinCurrentLimitations)). Power = voltage * current (p = i * v) and VCC is 5V. This means the total amount of power your Arduino can supply is 1 watt. This is likely significantly less than the amount of power required to turn on your light bulb.

The purpose of the resistor in the LED circuit is to limit the current going through the LED. This is more commonly done when the LED is connected directly to a GPIO pin in order to prevent more current from being drawn from a pin than the amount that will damage that pin. From the same source as the current limit from VCC, the limit for a GPIO pin is only 40 mA. I would recommend seeing if you can power your light bulb with a battery. You could then use this same size battery as the power source for your relay board.